# как растянуть background под toolbar? сам toolbar имеет прозрачный фон из картинки

Tags: android

то что имеется на данный момент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а нужно что то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

к слову изначально создавал пустое активити, поэтому изначально с созданием toolbara возникли проблемы, поэтому кусок кода вначале выглядит так:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inner_class);

        setTitle("title");
        BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.title_background));
        background.setTileModeX(android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

UPD: забыл еще такую немаловажную часть, что background запихан в layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".InnerClass"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
```

собственно это и является причиной почему оно не растягивается на весь экран, соответственно и вопрос, а куда пихать background чтобы он залил всю активность? в androidmanifest не получилось, не могу понять как.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что это не растягивать нужно, это нужно сделать ваш `toolbar` полупрозрачным. А вот дальше если вам нужно сделать вашу строку состоянию по цвету фона, то нужно поменять ее фон. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android) написано как сделать строку состояния по с нужным фоном.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте формат цвета RGB c прозрачностью

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/293028)

Comment: @Dmitry, мне кажется, что лучше переместить ваш комментарий под вопрос ТС, потому-что ответ под которым вы написали свой отзыв не имеет ничего общего с удаленным ответом.